# How to add a Lookup column to a collection

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I have a problem in my solution:

I want to add my lookup column (dropdown) to my collection called "colGridUpdates",

I have 2 lists, one is called "Projects" (this list has the lookupcolumn in it) and the other is called "Auftraggeber" (The list the lookup column refers to).

Here is my code:

```
If(
    IsBlank(
        LookUp(
            colGridUpdates;
            ID = ThisItem.ID
        )
    );
    Collect(
        colGridUpdates; 
        ThisItem
    )

);;
UpdateIf(
    colGridUpdates;
    ID = ThisItem.ID;
    {
        Title: txtTitle.Value;
        Bereich: drpBereich.Selected;
        Fälligkeitsdatum: datum1.Value;
        'Geändert am': datum2.Value;
        Auftraggeber: DropdownCanvas2.Selected;
        Organisation: drpOrganisation.Selected
    }
);;
```

this code is in a canvasbutton on the "on select" mode.

I need to have the Lookup column "Auftraggeber" in the collection "colGridUpdates", beacuase I use the collection to enable and disable the save button, if a row is edited.

If i edit the column "Auftraggeber" it don't reconize the change, and my button is enabled.

Code of my save button:

`If(CountRows(colGridUpdates)=0;DisplayMode.Disabled;DisplayMode.Edit)`

I tried to do a new collection that only contains the LookUp column. It didn't work because the collection was updated when i clicked on the other columns and not on the LookUp column.